# Using a Scanner to read '(' and ')'

Tags: java, char

I have a small problem while trying to use a scanner to read a .txt file. I am not sure how to identify an opening or closing parenthesis... For example

```
try {
    Scanner wf = new Scanner(file);
    wf.useDelimiter("");

    while (wf.hasNext()) { //40 up --- 41 down (ASCII)
        if(wf.next().equals('(')) {
            increase();
            System.out.println("Success");
        } else {
            decrease();
            System.out.println("No");
        }
    }

    wf.close();
}
```

I try to say if wf.next().equals('(') than increase my variable, otherwise decrease. But it does not identify any character in the .txt as a '(' character.

So how can I use the scanner to check if the character .next is an opening parenthesis?

Comment: Escape it. Escape it.

Comment: Your code comment refers to ASCII. Java uses Unicode/UTF-16 code units. "(" is indeed one code unit with the value of 40.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`equals` expects String, not Character. Use `"("` instead of `'('`.

Comment: Tested, can confirm this is answer to OP: `if(wf.next().equals("(")) {`

Comment: @Momo Thanks, but you don't need to write that comment. If you think that answer is correct you can simply up-vote it :)